# Debugging Delphi Firemonkey Indy TCP Server

Tags: delphi, debugging, tcp, firemonkey, indy

I have a Delphi Firemonkey application implementing a TCP server. The server is not opening the port as expected.  I can see the form open but netstat reveals that the port is not opened. I am now attempting to debug this issue by trying to put log messages.

The trouble is I have never used Firemonkey before. I am not sure where I can expect to see the log messages.

I have declared a logging service.

```
LoggingService: IFMXLoggingService;
```

And then I initialize it

```
LoggingService := FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXLoggingService) as IFMXLoggingService;
```

And then I call this inside the function `Tserver.Execute` to make sure that it is executed.

```
if Assigned(LoggingService) then
  LoggingService.Log('TserverExecute !',[]);
```

I am not sure where to expect the output. I have checked various debug terminals, can't seem to find the output string anywhere. It would be great if someone could point out what I am doing wrong?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Platform,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdContext,
  IdSocketHandle, IdUDPServer, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TserverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  LoggingService: IFMXLoggingService;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding : TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  LoggingService := FMX.Platform.TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXLoggingService) as IFMXLoggingService;
  TCPServer.DefaultPort := 16000;
  TCPServer.Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := TCPServer.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '0.0.0.0';
  Binding.Port := 16000;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TCPServer.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.TserverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  C : String;
begin
  C := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn();
  if Assigned(LoggingService) then
    LoggingService.Log('TserverExecute !',[]);
 if C = 'TESTSTRING' then
 begin
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Writeln('SENT');
 end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Why are you posting this as a new question? You deleted your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025843/) on this same topic, instead of addressing the comments posted on it. You should have answered what was asked on it so it could be re-opened.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I have put in the debug code.I didn't debug code before. Now I think my immediate concern is how to be able to debug using printf's so that I can understand it better and make some progress.

Comment: That is still no excuse for deleting the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025843/).  Just because it was put on hold does not make it invalid.  You were asked to provide more information about it, and you did not do that.  *That* question was about the port issue. *This* question is about logging instead.  Two separate questions, not related to each other, even if they are referring to the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure where to expect the output.

The documentation for [`IFMXLoggingService.Log()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXLoggingService.Log) says:

> Displays a message in the [Event Log](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Event_Log_Window).

The [Event Log](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Event_Log_Window) is a window inside the IDE itself (View > Debug Windows > Event Log). It displays log messages generated by an app during a debugging session.  So, you need to run your Firemonkey app inside the debugger in order to see the log messages from `IFMXLoggingService`.

Comment: I have tried this. In the event log in debug mode I get `Thread start`, `Process Start` and a series of `Module Load` messages. That is all. My debug messages can't be found

Comment: Which platform is your app running on?  What I said above applies to Windows (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631001/).

Comment: In that explanation I get that you have to register your custom logging service. But I don't get what `TMyLoggingService.Create` is? as in `MyLoggingService := TMyLoggingService.Create;`

Comment: Read the explanation again. It says **IF** you wanted to implement **custom** logging, you can (log to a file, an external service, whatever you need). It is not required in order to use logging in general. The explanation also points out how the **default** `IFMXLoggingService` implementation on Windows works (`OutputDebugString()`, which is handled by the IDE's Event Log).

Comment: Assuming that I want to, It still doesn't explain `IFMXLoggingService  does not contain a member named Create`

Comment: Read the code again more carefully, it is not calling `IFMXLoggingService.Create()`, it is calling `TMyLoggingService.Create()` and then assigning the resulting `TMyLoggingService` object to an `IFMXLoggingService` variable. The `TMyLoggingService` class is expected to implement the `IFMXLoggingService` interface. I have updated the code to show that.

Comment: Can I just use a simple `Writeln(Format)` in TMyLoggingService.Log()  and use that to output the message to event log ?

Comment: No you can´t. Writeln writes to the console. You need a basic knowledge of the programming tool and the platform you are going to program for **before** start programming. You will get that by reading the docs for both.

Comment: `WriteLn()` outputs to the calling process's console, if it has one. It does not output to the IDE's Event Log (I already told you how to do that - `OutputDebugString()`). Also, you need to use the `SysUtils.Format()` function to account for the `Params` parameter, don't log the `Format` parameter by itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I have used `OutputDebugString('HELLO WORLD WORLD WORLD');` just to check.It doesn't output it in the event log

Comment: I assure you, it does. But ONLY if your app is running inside the IDE debugger, since it is a debugging function. Are you doing that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Yes. I think so. I am using (F9) and It does show `Event Log`, `Breakpoint List` and `Thread Status` etc. But In the `Event Log` I see a log of messages `(mostly Module Load)`